# css3 before pseudo class

Tags: css

I'm trying to find out the difference between using one colon ":" and two "::" I see both of them are working with pseudo class. I have tried this with before pseudo class for example and when I did both ways it worked fine.

Is there any difference between two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially there was no difference! But this notation was introduced in CSS3 to distinguish between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes:

> This :: notation is introduced by the current document in order to
>   establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.
>   For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also
>   accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced
>   in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and
>   :after). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements
>   introduced in CSS level 3.

[the according section in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#pseudo-elements)